# 1)a workaround for "NMaximize" error "function unbounded." but don't know why 2) more importantly, how to speed up this 3d region plot (see update2)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

When I was trying to find the maximum value of `f` using `NMaximize`, mathematica gave me a error saying

`NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded.`

However, if I scale `f` with a large number, say, 10^5, 10^10, **even 10^100**,  `NMaximize` works well.

In the two images below, the blue one is `f`, and the red one is `f/10^10`.

Here come my questions:

1. Is scaling a **general** optimization trick?
2. Any other **robust, general workarounds** for the optimizations such
   needle-shape functions?
3. Because the scaling barely changed the shape of the needle-shape of
   `f`, as shown in the two images, **how can scaling work here?**

thanks :)

**Update1:** with `f` included

```
Clear["Global`*"]

d = 1/100;
mu0 = 4 Pi 10^-7;
kN = 97/100;
r = 0.0005;
Rr = 0.02;
eta = 1.3;

e = 3*10^8;

s0 = 3/100;

smax = 1/100; ks = smax/s0;
fre = 1; tend = 1; T = 1;
s = s0*ks*Sin[2*Pi*fre*t];
u = D[s, t];
umax = N@First[Maximize[u, t]];

(*i=1;xh=0.1;xRp=4.5`;xLc=8.071428571428573`;
i=1;xh=0.1;xRp=4.5;xLc=8.714285714285715;*)
i = 1; xh = 0.1; xRp = 5.5; xLc = 3.571428571428571`;
(*i=1;xh=0.1`;xRp=5.`;xLc=6.785714285714287`;*)

h = xh/100; Rp = xRp/100; Lc = xLc/100;
Afai = Pi ((Rp + h + d)^2 - (Rp + h)^2);
(*Pi (Rp-Hc)^2== Afai*)
Hc = Rp - Sqrt[Afai/Pi];
(*2Pi(Rp+h/2) L/2==Afai*)
L = (2 Afai)/(\[Pi] (h + 2 Rp));
B = (n mu0 i)/(2 h);

(*tx = -3632B+2065934/10 B^2-1784442/10 B^3+50233/10 B^4+230234/10 \
B^5;*)
tx = 54830.3266978739 (1 - E^(-3.14250266080741 B^2.03187556833859));

n = Floor[(kN Lc Hc)/(Pi r^2)] ;

A = Pi*(Rp^2 - Rr^2);
b = 2*Pi*(Rp + h/2);

(* -------------------------------------------------------- *)

Dp0 = 2*tx/h*L; 


Q0 = 0;

Q1 = ((1 - 3 (L tx)/(Dp h) + 4 (L^3 tx^3)/(Dp^3 h^3)) Dp h^3)/(
   12 eta L) b;
Q = Piecewise[{{Q1, Dp > Dp0}, {Q0, True}}];


Dp = Abs[dp[t]];


ode = u A - A/e ((s0^2 - s^2)/(2 s0 )) dp'[t] == Q*Sign[dp[t]];

sol = First[
   NDSolve[{ode, dp[0] == 0}, dp, {t, 0, tend} , 
    MaxSteps -> 10^4(*Infinity*), MaxStepFraction -> 1/30]];

Plot[dp''[t] A /. sol, {t, T/4, 3 T/4}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> All]
Plot[dp''[t] A /10^10 /. sol, {t, T/4, 3 T/4}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]

f = dp''[t] A /. sol;
NMaximize[{f, T/4 <= t <= 3 T/4}, t]
NMaximize[{f/10^5, T/4 <= t <= 3 T/4}, t]
NMaximize[{f/10^5, T/4 <= t <= 3 T/4}, t]
NMaximize[{f/10^10, T/4 <= t <= 3 T/4}, t]
```

**update2: Here comes my real purpose. Actually, I am trying to make the following 3D region plot. But I found it is very time consuming (more than 3 hours), any ideas to speed up this region plot?**

```
Clear["Global`*"]

d = 1/100;
mu0 = 4 Pi 10^-7;
kN = 97/100;
r = 0.0005;
Rr = 0.02;
eta = 1.3;

e = 3*10^8;

s0 = 3/100;

smax = 1/100; ks = smax/s0;
f = 1; tend = 1/f; T = 1/f;
s = s0*ks*Sin[2*Pi*f*t];
u = D[s, t];
umax = N@First[Maximize[u, t]];


du[i_?NumericQ, xh_?NumericQ, xRp_?NumericQ, xLc_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{Afai, Hc, L, B, tx, n, A, b, Dp0, Q0, Q1, Q, Dp, ode, sol, 
   sF, uF, width, h, Rp, Lc},
  h = xh/100; Rp = xRp/100; Lc = xLc/100;
  Afai = Pi ((Rp + h + d)^2 - (Rp + h)^2);

  Hc = Rp - Sqrt[Afai/Pi];

  L = (2 Afai)/(\[Pi] (h + 2 Rp));
  B = (n mu0 i)/(2 h);


  tx = 54830.3266978739 (1 - E^(-3.14250266080741 B^2.03187556833859));

  n = Floor[(kN Lc Hc)/(Pi r^2)] ;

  A = Pi*(Rp^2 - Rr^2);
  b = 2*Pi*(Rp + h/2);

  Dp0 = 2*tx/h*L;  


  Q0 = 0;

  Q1 = ((1 - 3 (L tx)/(Dp h) + 4 (L^3 tx^3)/(Dp^3 h^3)) Dp h^3)/(
    12 eta L) b;
  Q = Piecewise[{{Q1, Dp > Dp0}, {Q0, True}}];

  Dp = Abs[dp[t]];


  ode = u A - A/e ((s0^2 - s^2)/(2 s0 )) dp'[t] == Q*Sign[dp[t]];

  sol = First[
    NDSolve[{ode, dp[0] == 0}, dp, {t, 0, tend} , MaxSteps -> 10^4, 
     MaxStepFraction -> 1/30]];


  sF = ParametricPlot[{s, dp[t] A /. sol}, {t, 0, tend}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1];


  uF = ParametricPlot[{u, dp[t] A /. sol}, {t, 0, tend}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1];


  tdu = NMaximize[{dp''[t] A /10^8 /. sol, T/4 <= t <= 3 T/4}, {t, 
     T/4, 3 T/4}, AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6];

  width = Abs[u /. tdu[[2]]];

  {uF, width, B}]

RegionPlot3D[
 du[1, h, Rp, Lc][[2]] <= umax/6, {h, 0.1, 0.2}, {Rp, 3, 10}, {Lc, 1, 
  10}, LabelStyle -> Directive[18]]
```

[image: f]
[image: f/10^10]

Comment: Would you define the function, `f`?

Comment: Yes, please include `f`!

Comment: @David and Mr Wizard, thanks for your kindly concern. I thought it would be a little nasty to show `f` here. :). OK, I made two updates now.

Comment: Scaling or normalization is quite a standard technique in optimization.

Comment: @PlatoManiac, thank you very much. Would you please give me some suggestions on the question in my  update2  above? :)

Comment: @FreshApple that is a little overwhelming I admit, but at least now there is something to sink our teeth into.

Comment: First question:  why are there `ParametricPlot` call inside `du`?

Answer (score 0):

`NMaximize::cvdiv` is issued if the optimum improved a couple of orders of magnitude during the optimization process, and the final result is "large" in an absolute sense.  (To prevent the message in a case where we go from 10^-6 to 1, for example.)

So yes, scaling the objective function can have an effect on this.

Strictly speaking this message is a warning, and not an error.  My experience is that if you see it, there's a good chance that your problem *is* unbounded for some reason.  In any case, this warning is a hint that you might want to double check your system to see if that might be the case.